# Datepicker Jquery only allow set of dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How could I set datepicker to only allow selecting (for any year) '05/01', '08/01', '11/01', '01/02'?

```
$(".dateField").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    yearRange: '1900:2100'
});
```

If that is even possible, of course! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) to disable all other days(but it won't look good because almost all of the calendar will look disabled and will be harder to find out the enabled date)

```js
$(".dateField").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    yearRange: '1900:2100',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return [date.getDate() == 1 && [5, 8, 11, 1].indexOf(date.getMonth() + 1) >= 0]
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input class="dateField" />
```

It will be much better if you provide 2 select boxes(one with years and other with allowed dates) instead of a datepicker

Comment: Thanks, worked fine. It really did not look good, but that's none of my business :) I'm just a developer not the boss :D